# How to tell scikit-learn vectorizer use specific features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization

I have a set of features picked - up by hand. Not all of them are single words; some of them are bigrams and some other are trigrams. I want to model my texts - that are provided in the form of raw texts explicitly based on these features. How can I do that in sklearn? This is how I have defined my Vectorizer so far.

```
def initialize():
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3))
    return vectorizer
```

Answer (score 3):

`CountVectorizer` and `TfIdfVectorizer` allow you to specify the vocabulary to be used. Pass them as the keyword argument `vocabulary` to the constructor. Quote from the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html):

> **vocabulary**: Mapping or iterable, optional
>
> Either a Mapping (e.g., a dict) where keys are terms and values are
>   indices in the feature matrix, or an iterable over terms. If not
>   given, a vocabulary is determined from the input documents.